# What is difference between Kubernetes Jobs & Deployments

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment, kubernetes-jobs

I see that Kubernetes `Job` & `Deployment` provide very similar configuration. Both can deploy one or more pods with certain configuration. So I have few queries around these:

- Is the pod specification `.spec.template` different in `Job` & `Deployment`?
- What is difference in `Job`'s `completions` & `Deployment`'s `replicas`?
- If a command is run in a `Deployment`'s only container and it completes (no server or daemon process containers), the pod would terminate. The same is applicable in a `Job` as well. So how is the pod lifecycle different in either of the resources?

Comment: simply put: deployments are used for services that are expected to be up and running continuously. think webservers, databases, etc. 

jobs/cronjobs are meant for tasks that are meant to be run and exit after they have finished. think: database backups, etcs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Many resources in Kubernetes use a [Pod template](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#pod-templates). Both `Deployments` and `Jobs` use it, because they manage Pods.

> Controllers for workload resources create Pods from a pod template and manage those Pods on your behalf.

> PodTemplates are specifications for creating Pods, and are included in workload resources such as Deployments, Jobs, and DaemonSets.

The main difference between `Deployments` and `Jobs` is **how they handle a Pod that is terminated**. A Deployment is intended to be a "service", e.g. it should be up-and-running, so it will try to restart the Pods it manage, to match the desired number of replicas. While a Job is intended to execute and successfully terminate.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding spec.template: both Job and Deployment would include a similar definition. See: https://v1-21.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#podtemplate-v1-core

Job completions and parallelism lets you split a task in sub-tasks. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#parallel-jobs , https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/indexed-parallel-processing-static/ . Replicas in a Deployment would not offer this.

In a Deployment, the default restartPolicy of your Pod is set Always. In a Job: Never. A job is not meant to restart your container once it would have exited. A deployment is not meant to exit.